# Replace all text in text file using regular expression

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a text file with following text

```
161624.406 : Send:[sometext1]
161624.437 : Send:[sometext2]
161624.468 : Send:[sometext3]
161624.499 : Send:[sometext4]
161624.531 : Send:[sometext5]
```

I want to keep only the *sometext* part in that file. Desired output is

```
sometext1
sometext2
sometext3
sometext4
sometext5
```

I am using the following code in Excel-VBA

```
Public Sub testa()
    a = "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.log"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 1)
    strText = objTxtFile.ReadAll
    objTxtFile.Close
    Set objTxtFile = Nothing


    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\[([^]]+)\]"
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strText)
        b = objRegMC(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With
    Set objRegEx = Nothing

    Debug.Print b
End Sub
```

The problem is the output is displayed as *sometext1* only. How do I `ReplaceAll` in the text file and save the file with the desired text only.

Comment: I assume it is ok to essentially delete the file and recreate it or do you need it to operate on the same file?

Comment: That is not a critical thing ... I can do either

Comment: @pnuts - Yes. But my requirement is to change the file itself as I am going to use that file in some other application too which is not Excel based and that app needs the file with stripped text only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `regex.Replace` method should do the trick.

Separate your pattern into groups like this: `"(.*?)(\[)([^]]+)(\])(.*?)"`

And now you can replace your input string with the matching group which is group three in this case: `objRegEx.Replace(strText, "$3")`

---

Here is a [helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521004) to different examples of Regex within Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already got your answer. But for a simple program like this, why even utilize regular expressions? Here's a 4 line script that can do the same thing - yes it has been tested.

```
Dim a, text: a = "C:\testenv\test.log"
text = split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(a, 1).ReadAll, vbcrlf)
for i=0 to ubound(text) : text(i) = replace(split(text(i), "[")(1), "]", "") : next
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(a, 2).Write(Join(text, vbcrlf))
```

Comment: Personally I would expand this to be more readable so its easier to understand, maintain and learn from.  Other than that, +1 Nice simple solution for the text format given by OP.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Thanks man! :) I must admit, I've found some rather unusual formats to manipulate text due to the fact that Regular Expressions can make my brain throb.

Comment: @Rich - Nice one .... but I wanted to use regular expression as my actual problem is bit complex. I posted my test code and data to get some insights from SO community.

Comment: @PankajJaju Makes sense. Glad you got it resolved. Thanks for the +1's gents!

Answer (score 0):

The regex obviously only grabbing the first match of the string.  I'm not proficient enough with regex to come up with a regex only solution that takes into account `\n`

A simple workaround would be to use `objTxtFile.ReadLine` instead of `ReadAll`

Read each string in one by one, apply regex and get output.

```
Public Sub testa()
    a = "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.log"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 1)

    Do Until (objTxtFile.AtEndOfStream) 'Loop till EOF
        strText = objTxtFile.ReadLine 'Single line read instead of ReadAll

        Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With objRegex
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = "\[([^]]+)\]"
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strText)
            b = objRegMC(0).SubMatches(0)
        End With
        Set objRegex = Nothing

        Debug.Print b 'replace this with the code to output the string where you want etc
    Loop
    objTxtFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have found a faster way to do it.

Comment: Try setting your text line to this: `objRegEx.Replace(strText, "")` and then you wont need `objRegMC`.  Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521004) that has an example of replacing the original excel cell using regex which is similar.

Comment: @PortlandRunner - Using Replace, I ended up replacing the required substring.

Comment: @PortlandRunner - Actually I used your idea and I think it can be done. I just need to change my patter to `.Pattern = "(.*?)(([^]]+)\])(.*?)"` and `objRegEx.Replace(strText, "$2")`. The only problem now is to remove the square brackets.

Comment: @PankajJaju I see now what you meant.  Can you move the square bracket into a new grouping `([)`

Comment: @PortlandRunner - That was easy :-). `.Pattern = "(.*?)(\[)([^]]+)(\])(.*?)"` and `objRegEx.Replace(strText, "$3")` ... Voilà !!!

Comment: @PortlandRunner - Put it in answer section ... will tick it cause that is what i actually needed and it is the most elegant and fastest way i believe

Answer (score 0):

OK ... found a way to do it (Thanks MSDN ... sometimes the docs are useful :-)). Sharing the answer

```
Public Sub testa()
    a = "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.log"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 1)
    strText = objTxtFile.ReadAll
    objTxtFile.Close
    Set objTxtFile = Nothing

    b = ""
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\[([^]]+)\]"
        Set objMatches = .Execute(strText)

        For Each Match In objMatches
            For Each SubMatch In Match.SubMatches
                b = b & SubMatch & vbCrLf
            Next SubMatch
        Next Match

    End With
    Set objRegEx = Nothing

    Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 2)
    objTxtFile.Write b
    objTxtFile.Close
    Set objTxtFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT** - Based on @PortlandRunner's suggestion

```
Public Sub testa()
a = "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.log"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 1)
strText = objTxtFile.ReadAll
objTxtFile.Close
Set objTxtFile = Nothing

b = ""
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "(.*?)(\[)([^]]+)(\])(.*?)"
    b = objRegEx.Replace(strText, "$3")
End With
Set objRegEx = Nothing

Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(a, 2)
objTxtFile.Write b
objTxtFile.Close
Set objTxtFile = Nothing
End Sub
```